# Vue + Vuex not getting values from state

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuex

its my first time using Vuex. I have my 2 arrays in the **$store.state**, one with **cart[]** empty array and another one **Lessons[]** with lesson parameters inside it.

I consol'ed log it and it succesfully adding new lessons to cart **$store.state.cart.join() gives me this output:**  `[{"lessonID":1003,"lessonTitle":"Lessons","lessonActivity":"English","lessonLocation":"Kensington","lessonPrice":"80","lessonAvailability":5}]` 
 
So how i can get this info in another component? I have tried to do this:

```
<div class="col-7 bg-secondary" v-for="(lesson, id) in $store.state.cart" :key="lesson.id">
                <div class="card" >
                    <img :src="$store.state.cart.url" alt="" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title">{{ $store.state.cart[id].Title }}</h3>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Subject: {{ $store.state.cart.Activity }} </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Location: {{ $store.state.cart.Location }} </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Price: {{ $store.state.cart.Price }} </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item text-danger">Availability: {{ $store.state.cart.Availability }} </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

but unfortunatelly nothing is shown and neither any errors is shown. Just to confirm I have added nothing in computed properties or anything in `<script>` tag. Please help me :/

Comment: If you don't have anything in `<script>` how do you expect `$store` to be defined in `<template>`? Relevant documentation [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper). Note Vuex also has very videos, particularly useful for beginners. But you do need a bit of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$store.state.cart.join()` is correct and returns what you say, a single object in array, you can add a computed property as:

```
<script>
export default {
    computed: {
      lesson() {
      return $store.state.cart.join()[0]
    }
}
</script>
```

Then in your template don't need v-for but you do:

```
<h3 class="card-title">{{ lesson.Title }}</h3>
```

Then again, I don't see Title attribute in the array returned but I assume it's correct given the code provided.

Comment: I followed one tutorial on youtube which is doing same like you, just without join(). because i did new variable with join() just to see if im actually retrieving info about what i added to 'cart' array. Unfortunately i dont know why its not showing me anything...  this is how computed looks
computed: {
 cart() {
  return this.$store.state.cart;
 }}
and in the template im just trying to do {{ cart.Activity }} for example and there's nothing, no errors, just empty blank...

Comment: Ok, so what i needed to do is write how i inserted in array. like i did: 

lessonID: this.$store.state.Lessons[index].id           
So in array i need to display not cart.id, but cart.lessonID

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that your outer `<div>` is not closed?

```html
<div class="col-7 bg-secondary" v-for="(lesson, id) in $store.state.cart" :key="lesson.id">
                <div class="card" >
                    <img :src="$store.state.cart.url" alt="" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title">{{ $store.state.cart[id].Title }}</h3>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Subject: {{ $store.state.cart.Activity }} </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Location: {{ $store.state.cart.Location }} </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Price: {{ $store.state.cart.Price }} </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item text-danger">Availability: {{ $store.state.cart.Availability }} </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i just copied the info that is needed for solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

So @catmal, was kind of correct, but i just needed to display not $store.state.cart.Activity 
but use @catmal explanation and then write parameter as i defined it

```
 computed: {
            cart() {
                return this.$store.state.cart;
            }
        }
```

and then
`<div class="col-7 bg-secondary" v-for="car in cart"> <p>asd {{ car.lessonID }} </p>`
It was wrong because i was trying to display `car.id` for example (it was defined like this in my store.js

thanks for the help